# My html navbar not working well in phone screen

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

Hey I am using tailwind css to complete my website. My navbar doesn't gives me full screen view in phone screen. Please help!!!

[ScreenShot of bug Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggZxr.png)

You can check original site hosted on github - [Website Link](https://notaryanxd.github.io/ncert-solutions/)

HTML and Tailwind-CSS :

```
<nav class="flex justify-between bg-blue-500 w-full">
        <div class="ncrt-sol mx-48 my-6">
            <span class="text-white font-bold text-xl cursor-default">NCERT Solutions</span>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <ul class="flex mx-40 my-6">
                <li><a href="#" class="mx-8 text-white font-bold text-lg hover:text-blue-500 hover:bg-white px-6 py-2 hover:rounded-3xl duration-150">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="solution.html" class="mx-8 text-white font-bold text-lg hover:text-blue-500 hover:bg-white px-6 py-2 hover:rounded-3xl duration-150">Solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="mx-8 text-white font-bold text-lg hover:text-blue-500 hover:bg-white px-6 py-2 hover:rounded-3xl duration-150">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I tried width-full by using `w-full` class but it is still not working...

Comment: As far as I am not able to see the error in the code you share, check https://play.tailwindcss.com/Z9vGQ9sqOh?size=748x720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with class `w-screen` which will compile to `100%vw`

**Edit**:

The margin of classes `ncrt-sol` and `flex` class is too high for mobile devices.

So this is causing the trouble . So instead of `mx-40` change it to `mx-4`

So the final code is :

```
<nav class="flex justify-between bg-blue-500 w-full">
        <div class="ncrt-sol mx-4 my-6">
            <span class="text-white font-bold text-xl cursor-default">NCERT Solutions</span>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <ul class="flex mx-4 my-6">
                <li><a href="#" class="mx-8 text-white font-bold text-lg hover:text-blue-500 hover:bg-white px-6 py-2 hover:rounded-3xl duration-150">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="solution.html" class="mx-8 text-white font-bold text-lg hover:text-blue-500 hover:bg-white px-6 py-2 hover:rounded-3xl duration-150">Solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="mx-8 text-white font-bold text-lg hover:text-blue-500 hover:bg-white px-6 py-2 hover:rounded-3xl duration-150">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

[image]

And change the margin likewise and use breakpoints for larger screen like `md:` `lg:` and the like.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried not working!

Comment: I went through the code, figured out the margin problem , i have changed the solution. If it is helpful , mark it as green tick. It would help others

Comment: Ok i tried the change mx class to 4 but my initial margin got to less. I want it to look like as it is now without any change and my problem should be fixed. I hope u would understand me. coz i have quite bad english

Comment: should i try padding instead? let me try

Comment: I suggested you try something like `mx-6 md: mx-12 lg: mx-48` i.e by default it will be for the very small devices i.e mobile devices and `md` is for devices like tablet and `lg` is for laptop screen

Answer (score 1):

The margin left and right of the `.ncrt-sol` `div` and `.links` `div` are too big for mobile screen and causing it to overflow the `body` element. Try to use a smaller value for mobile devices.